# PHP Array matching and counting the matched values

Tags: php, arrays, count, match

I have two compare two values (say $sid1 and $sid2) and match them and find out the total number of similar and dissimilar values (I mean count the values). Please help me by giving the coding for

1)  Storing the values fetched from while loop in array

2)  Comparing the two arrays to count the similar and dissimilar values

```
**My Program**

$sql="select * from table1 where qn1='$op2'";
$ds=mysql_query($sql);

while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($ds)) {
    $sid1=$r[‘a’];
    //need correct syntax for the below
    $a[]= $sid1;
}

$sql2="select * from table2 where qn4='$op3'";
$ds2=mysql_query($sql2);

while ($r2=mysql_fetch_array($ds2)) {
    //need correct syntax for the below
    $sid2=$r2[‘a’];
    $b[]= $sid2;
}

//how to match the array and count
Array ($a[] == $b[])
```

Comment: whats that thing \*\*My program\*\*?

Comment: did you want to put it bold in SO syntax?

Comment: mysql_ functions are deprecated, please use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/tr/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your first line is wrong. use `#My Program` instead of `**my program**`
also you can store you results directly into your array.
and remember that `mysql()` is being departed from `php` so you should use `mysqli()` functionalities.
and for your propose you should use `array_intersect()` function. it returns an array of match items. and you can use `sizeof()` function for counting the number of match items, so your codes shoul be like this:

```
<?php
$sql="select * from table1 where qn1='$op2'";
$ds=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
 while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ds))
{
$a[]= $r['a'];
}
$sql2="select * from table2 where qn4='$op3'";
$ds2=mysqli_query($connection,$sql2);
while ($r2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ds2))
{
$b[]= $r2['a'];
}
$match_items=array_intersect($a, $b);
$count=sizeof($match_items);
?>
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use # as a comment.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde there are three methods for commenting:
// and # for single line
and /* comment */ for single and multi line

Answer (score 0):

Below program can help you.

When you **SELECT *** in the SQL Table then the SQL TABLE **might have more than one column** resulting multidimensional array like below.

```
array (size=200)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '18' (length=2)
      'email' => string 'abc@xyz.com' (length=11)
      'userName' => string 'abc' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '19' (length=2)
      'email' => string 'cdf@xyz.com' (length=11)
      'userName' => string 'cdf (length=3)
  2=>
    ....
  3=>
    ....
```

then you have to check **whether whole row of one table** is matching with **another table whole row**. So you can achieve it by below method.

```
<?php
// DB Connection    
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=HOSTNAME;dbname=DB_NAME;charset=utf8', 'DB_USER_NAME', 'DB_PASSWORD', array( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ) );

//Queries
$sql_query1 = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE `qn1` = 'ABC';";
$sql_query2 = "SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE `qn2` = 'XYZ';";

$data1 = $db -> query( $sql_query1 ) -> fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$data2 = $db -> query( $sql_query2 ) -> fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

$notFound = array();
$found = array();
foreach ($data1 as $key => $value1) {
    foreach ($data2 as $key => $value2) {
        if( array_diff( $value1, $value2 ) ){
            // NotFound Array
            $notFound[] = $value1;
        } else {
            // Found Array
            $found[] = $value1;
        }
    }
}

echo "Not Found data1 Elements in data2 :  " . count( $notFound ) . "\n<br/> Found data1 Elements in data2 :" . count( $found ) ;
```